# Which algorithm does R use under the hood to calculate the variance?

Tags: r, algorithm, precision, variance

There are several more and less numerically robust and precise algorithms to calculate the variance of a data sample `x`. For example, there is a formula with high precision (see refs below), roughly equivalent to

```
( sum((x - mean(x))^2) - (sum(x - mean(x))^2)/length(x) )/length(x)
```

which is slightly inefficient because it does two passes through the data. The mathematically equivalent formula `mean(x^2)-mean(x)^2` is on the other hand more prone to catastrophic cancellation. There are many other algorithms out there, some of which only do one pass through the data; see for example the reviews in [Chan, Golub, LeVeque](https://doi.org/10.2307/2683386) or [Ling](https://doi.org/10.2307/2286154).

Which algorithm does R use under the hood to calculate the variance with the function `var()`? I read the manual pages of the function but they don't say anything about the specific algorithm used. I am not a programmer and have some difficulty understanding what happens in the underlying C code.

Answer (score 3):

If your looking for `stats::var`, just type it.

```
stats::var

function (x, y = NULL, na.rm = FALSE, use) 
{
    if (missing(use)) 
        use <- if (na.rm) 
            "na.or.complete"
        else "everything"
    na.method <- pmatch(use, c("all.obs", "complete.obs", 
        "pairwise.complete.obs", "everything", "na.or.complete"))
    if (is.na(na.method)) 
        stop("invalid 'use' argument")
    if (is.data.frame(x)) 
        x <- as.matrix(x)
    else stopifnot(is.atomic(x))
    if (is.data.frame(y)) 
        y <- as.matrix(y)
    else stopifnot(is.atomic(y))
    .Call(C_cov, x, y, na.method, FALSE)
}
<bytecode: 0x000001f7636f08f8>
<environment: namespace:stats>
```

And in `.Call(C_cov,...)` it calls `C` object [cov.c](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/56becd21c75d104bfec829f9c23baa2e144869a2/src/library/stats/src/cov.c). You can find out algorithm for `var` at that link.